# Permission denied for a "drw-r--r--" directory

Tags: unix, debian

I have a log/ directory with read permission for all : `drw-r--r--`

```
paul@ns387656:/var$ ls -l
...
drw-r--r--  9 root     root  4096 May 22 14:49 log
...
```

But when I want to access it with the cd command I have a "Permission denied"

```
paul@ns387656:/var$ cd log
-sh: cd: log: Permission denied
```

And I don't know why...

Ideas ?

Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need execute permission to change into a directory.
Also the owner is listed first.  In this case the owner is root and root has read and write permission.  Group and Others have only read permission.

Try this:

```
sudo chmod a+rx log
```

This adds read/execute permission for owner, group, and others.